# iPhone app builds to simulator, won't build to device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

**Update 2**

One of my other targets builds fine to device... looking at the difference in dependencies now.

**================**

**Update**

I have now installed new Xcode on a different computer, and I get the same result.

**================**

I have an app that builds OK to the simulator, but when I build to any device, it fails, and gives no errors.

When I look at the Log Navigator, I see this message:

```
Build operation failed without specifying any errors. Individual build tasks may have failed for unknown reasons. Some of these (up to 12) may be listed below.
```

That is the only error I see. I just installed XCode on this new computer, and it is XCode 4.5, including the iOS6 SDK. My partner is able to build the app just fine to the same devices, but she is on an older version of XCode, without iOS6.

[image]

Comment: “Some of these (up to 12) may be listed below.” 
Do you have any more information in the console?

Comment: No, nothing else after that... it's quite cryptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update multiple frameworks I depended on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have iOS6 installed on your device to put apps in it. Do you have iOS6 GM on your device?

Comment: Upgrading the phone to iOS6 did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device is on the latest version of iOS i.e iOS6.

Comment: But I can build to 5.1 simulator... why can't I build to a 5.1 device?

Answer (score 0):

I was still on Xcode 4.5.2 when I got this error. Two computer restarts fixed my problem.